# Having Problems with Node JS and AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am getting the flowing errors when I try to build out my app in elasitcbeanstalk

**var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log**

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/index.js:1:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

> app@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
 > node index.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
throw err;
```

- [Image of Elasticbeanstak Config Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2zHf.png)
- [My workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHbsc.png)

Comment: I think npm install is missing :s but elasticbean must to run it for you : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-packagejson.html

Comment: @JRichardsz Im bout to try that out now..

Comment: My Currter package.json

Comment: {
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Firsy Spp",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Answer (score 0):

Try in NodeCommand with : "npm install && npm run start"